# AMPScript SMS InsertDE() function not working in SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

It seems `InsertDE()` function is not working when triggered via SMS send (the code resides in the message body).

I have tested the same function with a dummy cloud page and it was working good. Has anyone here successfully used `InsertDE()` within a SMS message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `InsertDE()` function only works with email messages per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertde.htm):

> This function applies to email messages at send time only.

Instead, you should use [UpsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm): i.e. `UpsertData('SendDE',1,'_SubscriberKey',_SubscriberKey,'DateSent',NOW())`

> Use this function with landing pages and SMS messages only.